# Try failing when reading content from URL

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So I have a class with the following:

```
class NetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<String, StringBuilder, String> {

     @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int cp;
            while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1)
            {
                stringBuilder.append((char) cp);
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String string)
    {

    }
}
```

And it is being called here:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mediated);
    TextView welcome_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_view);
    new NetworkRequest().execute("https://graph.facebook.com/me");
    NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest();
    String string = networkRequest.doInBackground();
    test_view.setText(string);
}
```

When this is executed I am returning with "nothing" which explains it is falling in the catch statement of the doInBackground method, I get an exception of:

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are directly calling the doInBackground method on your main thread. Normally this method is run by doing the execute, which you are already doing...

Comment: NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest();
    String string = networkRequest.doInBackground();
    return string;  remove those three lines. And implement a decent onPostExecute where you set the result of doInBackgroud in your textview.

Comment: AsyncTask<String, StringBuilder, String>  change that to AsyncTask<String, String, String>

Comment: @greenapps This is what i was initially thinking but i cannot seem to understand how to return a string from the onPostExecute to the onCreate so it can be formatted to be shown in the textview

Comment: You will NOT return a string from onPostExecute to onCreate. Instead you will set that string in onPostExecute to your textview.

Comment: @greenapps Is it possible to set a textview from a different class?

Comment: Yes. But it is easier if your AsyncTask is an inner class of your Activity.

Comment: @greenapps I'm trying to keep a clean design pattern which is im trying to do stuff in different classes

Comment: There is nothing dirty in putting that little task in your activity. And for the moment you should be more concerned to get this running i think.

Comment: @greenapps True, I've removed the method calling and i am just using execute() but still when debugging its failing at the BufferReader line giving the same exception

Comment: Please update your code here. Also show your onPostExecute().

Comment: 'return "nothing". Better: return ex.getMessage(); As you will display result in a textview and so the user will see it.

Comment: @greenapps I don't have a onPostExecute(); I honestly don't have a clue how i would implement it with my code

Comment: If you just would google for asynctask example you would see how to add an onPostExecute to your AsyncTask.

Comment: @greenapps It's not clear how i am suppose to retrieve the string from the method and display in the textview

Comment: What is not clear? Adapt your code here and show what you tried.

Comment: The string is the String parameter of onPostExecute. And that is the same string as returned by doInBackground. That is how it works.

Comment: @greenapps i've updated what I have tried so far, i've tried returning a StringBuilder in the doInBackground then used StringBuilder in the param of the onPostExecute to return a string but it doesn't work

Comment: You are returning a String in doInBackground and that is ok. But you did not change  <String, StringBuilder, String> as i already asked before. And you have no code in onPostExecute. I told you already which code you should put there. Also place a log statement in it so you know it is called.

Comment: And and and.. you still have wrong code in onCreate!!!!

Comment: 'return null'. Do not do that. I also told you already what you had to put there before. Do as i suggest please as this story will never have an end...

Comment: @greenapps The code in the onCreate is correct though right? How else am i suppose to execute the method?

Comment: @Gusinator please check my answer edit..

Comment: No it is not correct. And i already told you which lines you had to remove. Why do i have to repeat that?

Answer (score 0):

Direct Reason for the Exception is that you shouldn't run Networking on your main thread, instead, run it in a background thread and only update your UI from it.

One way to do that is AsyncTask (as you are trying), another way is to use a library such as [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) which take care of the background threading for you.

Comment: But how do I return the string from the URL to present to the UI?

Comment: [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172496/android-volley-how-to-isolate-requests-in-another-class/30604191#30604191) can help you understand, I truly suggest to go through the links I posted in the answer, also, mind what @greenapps mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly invoke the doInBackground method of AsyncTask instead you should call execute method on your AsyncTask object which will take care executing the network request in the background thread.
developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html