# Android Studio - Using Volley to get JSON data from the server

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

This is my first attempt to create a login system in Android Studio and already got myself into trouble with my code.

My PHP script always returns something as JSON and I'm trying to parse that JSON in my LoginActivity, inside the login -method, but I'm getting
the following error after creditentials were forwarded to the server and the login button was clicked:

```
I/qtaguid﹕ Failed write_ctrl(u 43) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid﹕ Untagging socket 43 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ untagSocket(43) failed with errno -22
```

It did work earlier, when I was doing a stringRequest instead of jsonRequest, so everything should be fine on the server side. Since I'm very new to Android development, I'm unable to figure this one out by myself and need desperately your help.

Here's my LoginActivity without the imports:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Define Views
    private EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    private final String TAG = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // Hides the Action Bar for Login Activity

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); // Sets the Content View

        // Initializing Views

        // EditText fields
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        // Buttons
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        // Other
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // This method will set watcher for the EditTextFields
        // The method will watch the value set to the EditTextFields.
        // If there is nothing inputted in the EditTextField, "Login" button is disabled.
        // Correspondingly, if there are text in the field, "Login" button is enabled.
        watcher(editTextEmail, editTextPassword, buttonLogin);


        // On-Click listeners
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    // Watcher method to check the value of EditText field
    public void watcher(final EditText editText, final EditText editPassword, final Button button)
    {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (editText.length() == 0 && editPassword.length() == 0) // If length of the text field is equal to 0
                    button.setEnabled(false); // Disable the "Send" button
                else
                    button.setEnabled(true);  // Otherwise enable

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });

        if(editText.length() == 0 && editPassword.length() == 0)
            button.setEnabled(false); //disable at app start
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        // If the value of loggedIn variable is true
        if(!loggedIn) {

            // We will start the Courses activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CourseActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void login() {

        // Get the values from the edit texts
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        // Creating a JSON Object request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                // This line will not print out
                System.out.println(response);

                try {

                    String json_status = response.getString("status");
                    String message = response.getString("message");

                    if(json_status.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
                        System.out.println(message);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // You can handle the error here if you want
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                // Adding parameters to request
                params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                // Return parameters
                return params;

            }
        };

        // Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            // If button Login was clicked
            case R.id.buttonLogin:
                login(); // Start login method after "Login" button is clicked

                // startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("dbconnect.php");

// POST Variables
$post_email = $_POST['email'];
$post_password = $_POST['password'];

// Prepare the SQL query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':email' => $post_email,
  ));

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if($stmt->rowCount() > 0 && password_verify($post_password, $row['password']) && $row['role'] != 'staff') {

      $user = array(); // Create an array for the user information

      $user['id'] = $row['id'];
      $user['name'] = $row['name'];
      $user['email'] = $row['email'];
      $user['password'] = $row['password'];
      $user['role'] = $row['role'];

      // echo json_encode(["message" => "success"]);
      echo json_encode(["status" => "success", "message" => "Successfully logged in"]); // Format the array to JSON

} else {

    echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Incorrect creditentials"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be passing the params, I usually use this syntax:

```
 // Get the values from the edit texts
 final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
 final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

 Map<String, Object> params = new ArrayMap<>(2);
 // Adding parameters to request
 params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
 params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

    // Creating a JSON Object request
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
             {
              Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
              // other stuff ...
             }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
                {
                    // You can handle the error here if you want
                }
            }); 

    // Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Also, you might want to handle all the volley requests in a Singleton class, have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172496/android-volley-how-to-isolate-requests-in-another-class/30604191#30604191).

Hope this helps in any way :)

Comment: Yeah, it did. Thank you sir :)

Comment: @TommySM can you help me with this question I tried following your code.It is giving an exception JsonException Value stdClass of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020180/jsonexception-value-stdclass-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jso/34020554?noredirect=1#comment55796652_34020554