# JsonException Value stdClass of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json

Here I am trying to send `json` data to my webserver and using `php` I would like to parse the json and insert the data into mysql databse. I am getting an error saying Value stdClass of `type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.`

How can I resolve this error?

```
   private void insertToDb() throws JSONException {
    billType = (invEstSwitch.isChecked() ? textViewEstimate : textViewInvoice)
            .getText().toString();
    String invNumber = textViewInvNo.getText().toString();
    String bcode = barCode.getText().toString();
    String description = itemDesc.getText().toString();
    String wt = weightLine.getText().toString();
    String rateAmt = rateAmount.getText().toString();
    String making = makingAmount.getText().toString();
    String netr = netRate.getText().toString();
    String iTotal=itemtotal.getText().toString();
    String vatAmt =textViewVat.getText().toString();
    String sumAmt =textViewSum.getText().toString();
    String crtDate =textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("custInfo", custSelected.toString());
        jsonObject.put("invoiceNo", invNumber);
        jsonObject.put("barcode", bcode);
        jsonObject.put("desc", description);
        jsonObject.put("weight",wt );
        jsonObject.put("rate", rateAmt);
        jsonObject.put("makingAmt", making);
        jsonObject.put("net_rate",netr);
        jsonObject.put("itemTotal",iTotal );
        jsonObject.put("vat", vatAmt);
        jsonObject.put("sum_total", sumAmt);
        jsonObject.put("bill_type", billType);
        jsonObject.put("date", crtDate);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        itemSelectedJson.put(index, jsonObject);
        index++;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   String jsonarray = itemSelectedJson.toString().trim();
    JSONObject jb= new JSONObject();
    jb.put("selected",itemSelectedJson);

 Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Array",jsonarray);


    final JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, INVEST_URL, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("JSONERROR",error.toString());
        }
    });



    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(objectRequest);

}
```

I am new to programming so any help is appreciated.Thank you:)

This is the stack trace:

```
12-01 17:17:50.840 16785-16785/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 345K, 9% free 8597K/9396K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
12-01 17:17:50.841 16785-16785/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine D/SELECTED_ITEMS: [{"custInfo":"Ujwal  9975022560","rate":"24000","weight":"21.00000","desc":"GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE","makingAmt":"200","sum_total":"RS.52094.46","vat":"RS.1021.46","itemTotal":"51073","barcode":"BQSP78BB","net_rate":"24200","date":"2015-12-01","invoiceNo":"1","bill_type":"Invoice"}]
12-01 17:17:50.897 16785-16785/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-01 17:17:50.897 16785-16785/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-01 17:17:51.259 16785-16785/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine D/JSONERROR: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value stdClass of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-01 17:21:47.657 16785-16792/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 536K, 8% free 8689K/9396K, paused 171ms, total 190ms
```

[image] This is what I see when I debug it.The problem is when i say JSONObject(params) it says params: size=1 objectRequest:"[]

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace please.

Comment: @Patrick i just added the stack trace please check.thanks :)

Comment: @Patrick thank you :) can you help with the answer?

Comment: I dont find `Value stdClass` anywhere. And can you tell where the exception really occurs. thanks

Comment: Check if there is some unseen characters in your json string. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15469907/4224337).

Comment: @Rami I saw that answer but I couldn't figure out how and where I could use it

Comment: @anup check my answer)

Answer (score 2):

in your code i think you are trying to convert string stdClass to json object so if you are doing this process then follow below code i am giving an example to convert string to json object

```
String json = {"phonetype":"N95","cat":"WP"};

try {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

    Log.d("My App", obj.toString());

} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + json + "\"");
}
```

Comment: my json array is something like [{"custInfo":"Ujwal  9975022560","rate":"24000","weight":"21.00000","desc":"GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE","makingAmt":"200","sum_total":"RS.52094.46","vat":"RS.1021.46","itemTotal":"51073","barcode":"BQSP78BB","net_rate":"24200","date":"2015-12-01","invoiceNo":"1","bill_type":"Invoice"}]

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ open this link and past your json array.. when i  past this json array its not valid json array error shows.

Comment: you have problem in JsonObjectRequest class because above code working fine. so please provide the code of this class.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're following is my [exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933160/android-studio-using-volley-to-get-json-data-from-the-server/33975269?noredirect=1#comment55796950_33975269), then please notice that I use a

```
Map<String,Object>
```

The params are inserted like this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new ArrayMap<>();
// Adding parameters to request
params.put("email", email); // here email is already a string,
params.put("password", password.toString()); // here password needs the conversion
```

Then I pass it straight into a request using a new anonymous JSONObject:

```
// Creating a JSON Object request
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params), ...
```

That way the casting goes through the Object class.

Also note that my syntax creates and puts these params outside and before the request.

EDIT:
the reason you see that the size is one, is because it is actually 1, this part:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("Array",jsonarray);
```

makes the map size 1, since you put only one object inside - 
the amount of key-value **mappings** is the value given for the map size, meaning - the number of keys that point to a value (and the value itself can be another Map, it would still only count as one), see [This Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for the full explanation on the Map Collection.

About the other part - I suggest trying to add the values you want to the Map and sending *that* inside the new JSONObject, I answered something else that might help you with this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833589/volley-request-with-raw-data/33975698#33975698).
Then - on the php side - print out what you get (to see that you do get it), once you get the params on the php side - you can start wrapping your head around parsing it.

Hope this helps in any way :)

Comment: please check the updated question.My problem is when i debug new JSONObject(params) says params:size=1 and an empty objectRequest[].

Answer (score 1):

size is **1** that is correct because you put in your map that way:

```
params.put("Array",jsonarray);
```

so the json would be **1** object `{"Array":[...]}` and you will have to access this object first before you can parse the array.

Comment: If you check the image you will see that the jsonarray is being put into params(Map) then why new  JsonObject(params) results in objectRequest:"[] i.e why is it blank.I think I am getting the exception because it is blank.Can you give a code example on how to insert multiple values into a mysql database using volley. It would be very helpful for beginners like me Thank you :)