# Volley Service doesn't enter callback

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I am trying to do http requests using the volley service, and i found a really usefull answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628142/how-to-make-separate-class-for-volley-library-and-call-all-method-of-volley-from) about how to organize the service for diferent http requests, so you don't need to do all that code for every request.

The request works fine and i got the result i want, but it never enters de callback on the mainActivity.

So this never gets executed:

```
void initVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("GJ","success");
            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Volley requester " + requestType);
                Log.d(TAG, "Volley JSON post" + "That didn't work!");
            }
        };
    }
```

**Here is my main activity:**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText usernameTxt;
    EditText passwordTxt;
    EditText emailTxt;
    RequestQueue queue;
    boolean formValid = false;
    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback;
    static final String TAG = "request12";

    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/register";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //hide status bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        initVolleyCallback();

        //inicialize queue with volley
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //inicialize form fields
        usernameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        emailTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

        //set text for developing stage
        usernameTxt.setText("afcosta5");
        passwordTxt.setText("moitarioavE10");
        emailTxt.setText("filipecosta_10@hotmail.com");

    }

    public void register(View view) {

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

        //get form data
        final String username = usernameTxt.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
        String email = emailTxt.getText().toString();
        Log.d("email",String.valueOf(isValidEmail(email)));

        if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
            emailTxt.setError("Invalid Email");
        }

        //inicialize a map with pair key value
        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Add form fields to the map
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);

        JSONObject sendObj = new JSONObject(params);

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

        mVolleyService.postDataVolley(URL,sendObj);



 void initVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("GJ","success");
            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Volley requester " + requestType);
                Log.d(TAG, "Volley JSON post" + "That didn't work!");
            }
        };
    }
```

I really don't know where is the issue, need some help

Answer (score 0):

remove "initVolleyCallback()" method from "onCreate()". Implements "IResult" interface like

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements IResult
```

then You'll have to implement override methods of IResult

```
@Override
public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response) {
    Log.d("GJ","success");
}

@Override
public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Volley requester " + requestType);
     Log.d(TAG, "Volley JSON post" + "That didn't work!");
}
```