# Get Request JsonArray with volley

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, android-volley

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628142/how-to-make-separate-class-for-volley-library-and-call-all-method-of-volley-from) question to reuse volley service across diferent acitivies, but he just use the JSONOBject to GET and POST request, i need to return a JSONArray because i return more then 1 items with my request.

**So i have something like this on my Volley Service:**`public void

```
getDataVolley(final String requestType, String url){
        Log.d("TRIED","TRIED0");
        try {
            Log.d("TRIED","TRIED");
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener
```

`() {`

```
  @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("TRIED","TRIED2");
            if(mResultCallback != null)
                mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("TRIED",error.toString());
            }
        });
        jsonArray.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(jsonArray);

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("TRIED","TRIED4");
    }
}`
```

**So i use this service on my main activity like this:**

**Initialize**

```
        initPlants();
    Log.d("RESULTCALL",mResultCallback.toString());

    mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

    mVolleyService.getDataVolley(GETREQUEST,URL);
```

**callback**

```
void initPlants(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("GJJJ","GJJJ1");
            }
        };
    }

    public void showToast(String message){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SimiliarPhotos.this,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
```

The problem is i get a error in the second parameter on my response(volleyService), saying that it requires a JsonObject.

My IResult want a JSONObject and not a JSONArray

Comment: can you post your response here ? it would be better to get an idea how your response will look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your interface like this

```
public interface IResult {
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response);
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONArray response);
    public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error);
}
// added a new method "notifySuccess" where params are requestType & JSONArray response
```

now come to your activity from where You call your volley. from "onCreate()" remove the "initPlants();" method. Write Your activity name like this

```
public class Your_Activity extends Activity implements IResult {
```

now Implement the override methods like

```
@Override
public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {

}

@Override
public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
// Here You'll receive Your response as Array. Retrieve Your result from response
}

@Override
public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
    Log.d("GJJJ","GJJJ1");
}
```

Comment: great answer, but i just keep getting my response in the service side and not in my actitivity you know why?

Comment: can't understand your question. can u please elaborate? didn't my answer help u?

Comment: i solved the question now, i just wanted 2 listeners but the interface wants me to create always the 3, thanks a lot :)