# Update textview in Android using Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How can I automatically (without any button) update my textview everytime server sends the new JSON object using android volley or any other library? It is a simple program having one text view only. I have pasted both files. I am getting JSON file every time I enter text from server side and want them to show in textview instantly.

mainactivity.java

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Will show the string "data" that holds the results
    TextView results;
    // URL of object to be parsed
    String JsonURL = "url_link";
    // This string will hold the results
    String data = "";
    // Defining the Volley request queue that handles the URL request concurrently
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Creates the Volley request queue
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Casts results into the TextView found within the main layout XML with id jsonData
        results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonData);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();


        // Creating the JsonObjectRequest class called obreq, passing required parameters:
        //GET is used to fetch data from the server, JsonURL is the URL to be fetched from.
        JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonURL, jsonObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("colorObject");

                            String color = obj.getString("colorName");
                         //   String desc = obj.getString("description");

                            data += "Color Name: " + color;

                            // Adds the data string to the TextView "results"
                            results.setText(data);
                        }
                        // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }
        );
        // Adds the JSON object request "obreq" to the request queue
        requestQueue.add(obreq);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/jsonData"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you can, please post any code and any screenshots necessary for us to if possible replicate what you want to do and/or better understand your request. Thanks!

Comment: What problem you are facing? I think your code is updating `TextView` after you got response form server.

Comment: It is updating only once when the app starts. If I change the value from the server (JSON) it is not updating the new value in the textview.

Comment: You have to request for data again

Comment: How..can somebody help me with the code plz

Comment: You can request for data in every one second or some interval.

Comment: I do not think timer will be a good idea. There must be some other way.

Comment: When something changed on server send a push notification to device and request again to get updated data.

Comment: How should I do that? Please help with code. I guess it will be a simple code.

Comment: Please create interface and pass context refer this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628142/how-to-make-separate-class-for-volley-library-and-call-all-method-of-volley-from

Comment: Let me know if this link not work for you @Jeetu Routela

Comment: Thanks to all for their valuable support but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alarm Manager. Alarm manager can be set to do something at a specific time in future e.g. at 15:30, or every (for example) one minute. According to [developers site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager):

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the
>   future

Comment: This is actually not a good idea as you would be wasting precious device compute even if data is not changed. The approach of push notification is better.