# Android : how to wait for a method to finish before continuing

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a method called `getData()` that is loaded early in the splash activity ; it basically connects to json and retrieves some strings from it .

**I have two problems :**

My first problem here is ... This method takes a few seconds to connect and retrieve data from json but my program seems not to wait and continue playing the next lines on code and running the `getData()` at the same time which is wrong . I need first to get some strings then play next code .

My second problem is that I want to call `getData()` two times again if the app fails to connect to json . this can be checked with a Boolean called `isupdated` that has a true value inside `getData()` if it was successfully connected . But again , its impossible to call the method `getData()` and wait it to finish .
None of these ways could help :

```
for(int x =0 , x<3 , x++ )
{
    if(!jsonfetch.isupdated) {jsonfetch.getData(splash.this)}
}
```

or

```
while (!jsonfetch.isupdated){
        jsonfetch.getData(splash.this);
    }
```

The condition is always false and it calls the method simultaniously because it doesn't wait it to finish before checking the condition again ...

I have tried so many solutions like Putting `getData()` on a thread and calling `join()` but it doesn't wait . I have also tried AsyncTask but it calls `onPostExecute()` before the method ends which I don't understand.

**Bellow is getData() Code**

```
    public static void getData(final Context context) {
    handleSSLHandshake();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, encryption.URL_main(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.i("update_statut","Start Fetch .");
                popup_msg = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.epopup_msg));
                banner = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.ebanner));
                banner2= jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.ebanner2));
                interstitial = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.einterstitial));
                interstitial_Inside = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.einterstitial_Inside));
                youtube_url = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.eyoutube_url));
                dialog_check = Boolean.parseBoolean(jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.dialog_check)));
                dialog_Image_URL =jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.dialog_Image_URL));
                dialog_URL = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.dialog_URL));
                dialog_txt= jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.dialog_msg));
                dialog_canceble= Boolean.parseBoolean(jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.dialog_canceble)));
                m3u_app_url = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.edownload_appurl));
                premium_url = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.emuimerp));
                premium_msg = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.epremium_msg));
                online_version=response.getString("ON_version");
                updated_version=response.getString("UP_version");
                url_version = jsonfect_Decryption(response.getString(encryption.eurl_version));
                activation = response.getString("act");

                isupdated=true;

                Log.i("update_statut","Ending Fetch .");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("json",""+e.getMessage());
                isupdated=false;
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("json",""+error.getMessage());
            isupdated=false;
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            String creds = String.format("%s:%s",encryption.USERNAME(),encryption.Password());
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            params.put("Authorization", auth);
            return params;

        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

**Bellow is the Splash Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    setContentView(R.layout._splash_java);


    /// Start Animation
    circle=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_circle);
    textView2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txtwelcome=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtwelcome);
    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
    startAnimation();

    // GET DATABASE DATA
    while (!jsonfetch.isupdated){
        jsonfetch.getData(splash.this);
    }

    // Check Version

                    onlineVersion = jsonfetch.online_version;
                    updatedVersion = jsonfetch.updated_version;
                    try {
                        currentVersion = splash.this.getPackageManager()
                                .getPackageInfo(splash.this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d("update_statut", "currentVersion value is " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    if ( onlineVersion == null || updatedVersion == null || onlineVersion.equals("null") || updatedVersion.equals("null")  ) {
                        Log.d("update_statut", "online_Version or updated_Version issue");
                        Log.d("update_statut", "Current version " + currentVersion + " & Online version " + onlineVersion + " & Updated version " + updatedVersion);
                        check_version = true;
                        jsonfetch.isupdated = false;
                    } else if ((currentVersion.equals(onlineVersion))) {
                        Log.d("update_statut", "match");
                        Log.d("update_statut", "Current version " + currentVersion + " & Online version " + onlineVersion);
                        check_version = true;
                        Interstitial_LOAD();
                    } else if ((currentVersion.equals(updatedVersion))) {
                        Log.d("update_statut", "match");
                        Log.d("update_statut", "Current version " + currentVersion + " & Updated version " + updatedVersion);
                        check_version = true;
                        Interstitial_LOAD();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("update_statut", "doesn't match");
                        Log.d("update_statut", "Current version " + currentVersion + " & Online version " + onlineVersion);
                        check_version = false;
                    }



    /// Load Next Activity after 5s so that Interstitial can be loaded


            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            if(  (!check_version) && jsonfetch.isupdated){
                update_dialog();
                Log.d("update_statut", "Update dialog ");
            } else {
                Interstitial_SHOW();
            }
        }
    }, 5000);

}



private void Interstitial_LOAD()  {
    String inter_code = jsonfetch.interstitial;
    if ( inter_code!=null && !(inter_code.equals("null") || inter_code.equals("") )  ){
        AdRequest adRequestI = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(inter_code);
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequestI);
    }
}




    private void Interstitial_SHOW() {

    String inter_code = jsonfetch.interstitial;
    if ( inter_code!=null && !(inter_code.equals("null") || inter_code.equals("") )  )
    {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.show();
            interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(splash.this, first_java.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
                    splash.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(splash.this, first_java.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
            splash.this.finish();
        }
    }

    else {
        startActivity(new Intent(splash.this, first_java.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
        splash.this.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out AsyncTask : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: @aomerk I have also tried AsyncTask but it calls onPostExecute() before the method ends which I don't understand.

Comment: Add a callback parameter to `getData` and have the `onResponse` invoke the callback.  Put your remaining code (from `// Check Version` on) inside the callback implementation.  The `onResponse` is dispatched by volley on the main thread.  (This is also most likely why your AsyncTask approach didn't work - the volley request is async so your background work was finishing immediately.)

Comment: @Andy thank you for your reply  , could you please clarify more

Comment: This answer has an example of how to implement a callback for a volley request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604191/2711811.

Answer (score 0):

REGARDING YOUR FIRST CONCERN ...

If you want to pause then use
 java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit:

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

To sleep for one second or more

TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);